# BraintreeHttp-Dotnet.dll | I need to strongly sign this assembly to use in a .Net 4.6.1 project

Tags: c#, paypal, asp.net-core-2.0, braintree

The Version 2 checkout PayPalCheckoutSdk depends on BraintreeHttp-Dotnet.dll. The PayPalCheckoutSdk is strongly signed for use in .Net 4.6.1 however the BraintreeHttp-Dotnet.dll is not strongly signed. This makes the PayPalHttpClient throw an exception when accessed:

```js
"Could not load file or assembly 'BraintreeHttp-Dotnet, Version=0.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)"
```

The BraintreeHttp-DotNet.dll is not available on their github site so I'm unable to add my own key to strongly sign it.

I'm in a catch 22 situation as I must compile my project in .Net rather than .Net Standard.

Is there a solution available - or workaround?

Answer (score -2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

We added Strong Naming support in version [2.54.0 of our .NET SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2540). I would ensure that you are at least on this version, but highly recommend using the latest version which is [4.11.0](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#4110).

Comment: I require BraintreeHttp-DotNet.dll which is NOT part of your .Net SDK.